# GBDT- randomized repetition feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, boosting

Consider the following approach for feature selection in the specific case of gradient boosting decision trees:

1. Randomly pick X% of features
2. Run algorithm
3. Record importance of each feature
4. Repeat many times

At the end - rank all features according to their importance within each loop - using mean or mode or something else

Questions

- would this approach make sense
- does it have a name
- any examples online?

Comment: It's common practice with GBDTs to use a random subset of features when building each tree. Out of curiosity, why do you want to perform feature subsampling in an 'outer loop' and run GBDT multiple times instead?

Comment: I have a large number of features which are very close to each other in terms of importance - probably because they are very similar - and i am trying to distinguish which ones to keep really

Comment: What you describe seems reasonable (with a large caveat) but I cannot see what would be the advantage of it than say run a "standard" random forest and rank features based on permutation. If you suspect that some of features encode redundant information wouldn't it make sense to use some dimensional reduction algorithm and just use the use the condensed dataset? A caveat of your approach is that the feature importance metric is additive. What if for example the algorithm is a ridged GLM and we just pick $t$-values? Is that relevant?

Comment: Just musing about the subject: I *guess* one could go crazy and treat each subset as a team and each feature as a player and then rank all the possible teams and then find the best players. That is very similar to what a Shapley value calculation does for model explanations but we would focus on the magnitude rather than the directionality of the change... Why brings me back to the original suggestion: why not just reduce the dimensions of the inputs and/or use an RF/GBM directly?